# Configuring spring boot application from tomcat to jetty

Tags: spring-boot

Consider a spring boot web application that is deployed using a tomcat server
Now I want to change the server from tomcat to jetty. Is it possible? or some 
easy way to configure it

Comment: Check out my blog https://stacktips.com/articles/replace-tomcat-with-jetty-or-undertow-in-spring-boot

Comment: or this youtube video https://youtu.be/1gEoiMVULt4

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, replace this dpendancy from the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please note that there are some other starters e.g. ThymeLeaf templating engine, etc. that might pull in Tomcat by default. If you’re using one of these, you’ll have to manually exclude Tomcat from all such dependencies.

Comment: ok. So just changing the dependency is enough to change the server?

Answer (score 1):

To use the embedded Jetty server instead of Tomcat, you need to exclude the spring-boot-starter-tomcat from `spring-boot-starter-web` and include the `spring-boot-starter-jetty` dependency.

Also, you will need to exclude the default added spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency.

**For Spring Boot Version 2.x.x**

For Gradle, make the following changes to your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group:'org.springframework.boot', module:'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
}
```

If you’re using Maven build tools, you need to add this to your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**For Spring Boot Version 3.x.x**

The above configuration works for Spring Boot version 2.x, but it will throw the following error if you’re using the latest Spring Boot version 3.x.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext 
with Spring Boot 3 and Jetty server
```

This is because Jetty does not yet support Servlet 6.0. To use Jetty with Spring Boot 3.0, you will have to downgrade the Servlet API to 5.0. You can use the `jakarta-servlet.version` property to do so.

```
ext['jakarta-servlet.version'] = '5.0.0'
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    modules {
        module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat") {
            replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
        }
    }
}
```

If you’re using Maven build tools, you need to add this to your pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```